# Nice small slide in / out notification for Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, jquery-plugins

in many places in application I have buttons/inline edits that cause AJAX requests. However now users don't receive any feedback about the action.

Do you know any plugin that will display (slide in) a small box at the top of the page (something like here on StackOverflow, but smaller like 100px width with text: Saving...) with a message once I perform the request, and then I could it fade out once request is done?

Comment: Is `ajax loading indicator` what you are looking for? There are a lot of questions about this already on SO.

Comment: http://needim.github.com/noty/

Comment: needim.github.com/noty ?! That is great!!

Comment: @eicto: why not post this as answer, as I didn't know about this before (I, as said in the answer, was using jGrowl), but this noty looks waaay more cool!

Comment: @eicto: why not post this as an answer? :)

Comment: @dragonfly I just made google "jquery notify plugin" and check the 2nd link :)

Comment: @eicto: http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/ - this is really crazy sh... I mean: stuff! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl on all my projects.

edit: as @eicto said in the comment [noty plugin](http://needim.github.com/noty/) looks pretty awesome, and I'll be looking into using that from now on as it has a lot more options.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own. Just the CSS and JS play the role. :)

#### HTML:

```
​<div class="notifications"​​​​​​​​​​>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

#### CSS:

```
​.notifications {border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #f5f5f5; width: 200px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}​
```

#### JavaScript:

```
​$(document)​.ready(function(){
    $(".notifications").css("top", -$(".notifications").height());
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".notifications").animate({top: 0}, 1000);
    }, 1000);
});​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kWuww/

#### Plugins:

1. [Noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/)
2. [Growl](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Growl)